# Why my server have less maximum number of queues than my processor?

Tags: linux-networking, linux-kernel, ubuntu-20.04

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 LTS with kernel version `5.4.0-117-generic` my machine have 12 thread of CPU using `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v3 @ 3.50GHz`. The problem is why my maximum multi-queue configuration is 4 it should be 12 right? following my vCPU number

```
# ethtool -l enp4s0
Channel parameters for enp4s0:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:             0
TX:             0
Other:          1
Combined:       4
Current hardware settings:
RX:             0
TX:             0
Other:          1
Combined:       4
```

My ethernet driver is

```
# ethtool -i enp4s0
driver: igb
version: 5.6.0-k
firmware-version: 3.16, 0x800004d7
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:04:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

I've check RX/TX queue is only 4

```
# ethtool -S enp4s0 | egrep 'rx_queue.*packets|tx_queue.*packets' | column -c 80
     tx_queue_0_packets: 1285500             rx_queue_0_packets: 9816392
     tx_queue_1_packets: 560302              rx_queue_1_packets: 2988942
     tx_queue_2_packets: 390412              rx_queue_2_packets: 2683848
     tx_queue_3_packets: 1865716             rx_queue_3_packets: 3764393
```

How can I increase number of maximum queue to the same with number of vCPU?

Comment: AFAIK it's a NIC hardware property.

Answer (score 1):

So I've check my NIC Hardware and it's using `Intel I210`

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. I210 Gigabit Network Connection
        Kernel driver in use: igb
        Kernel modules: igb
```

I've got the product detail in [here](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-briefs/ethernet-server-adapter-i210.pdf) that says:

> The I210 contains four transmit and four receive queues.

So I think I know why the maximum queues is only four

Comment: more information has been posted in Answer section. 
please move this section to your question.